# Maven deploy to Nexus failed with 502 code when using hostname instead of ip address

Tags: maven, nexus

Maven deploy to Nexus failed with 502 code when using nexus hostname instead of ip address.
when I use ip to deploy, it was suceed.

Maven distributionManagement:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <name>Internal Releases</name>
        <url>http://dev11:8082/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>Internal snapshots</name>
        <url>http://dev11:8082/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Error Infomation:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project myapplication-api: Failed to retrieve remote metadata com.mycompany.mygroup:myapplication-api:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata com.mycompany.mygroup:myapplication-api:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to snapshots (http://dev11:8082/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/): Failed to transfer file: http://dev11:8082/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/mycompany/mygroup/myapplication-api/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 502 , ReasonPhrase:No data received from server or forwarder. -> [Help 1]`

Comment: Are you surt that the port is correct? By default the port is 8081 ? Or have you configured it differently than the default?

Comment: can you successfully `ping` the host name?

Comment: It migth be proxy issue. If you define a rule (no proxy vs.) for that ip, try to define same rule to host name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know

I have added a proxy but not exclude the hostname

Fixed the problem after add

```
<proxy>
  ...
  <nonProxyHosts>dev11</nonProxyHosts>
```